# Can the function called by ScriptApp.newTrigger identify the triggerID?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

In my app script web app I have multiple triggers created with ScriptApp.newTrigger()

example:

```
function createTimeTriggerSpecifcDate(dateStr) {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  const trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("scriptToRunAt")
   .timeBased()
   .at(date)
   .create();
  return trigger.getUniqueId();
}

function scriptToRunAt(){
 ....
}
```

Is there a way for the called function "scriptToRunAt()" to know the trigger id?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events) provides the `triggerUid`:

```
function scriptToRunAt(eventObject){
 const uniqueId = eventObject.triggerUid;
}
```